# Tutorial on using Loop Helper for WebMatrix

Tags: asp.net, nuget

I just learned of the Nuget package [Loop Helper for WebMatrix](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/WebMatrixLoopHelper). Unfortunately I can't seem to find any documentation or project site. Does anyone have any information on how to use this or where the project site is?

Comment: FWIW I have seen the cshtml files it added to the project, but they don't really discuss anything about `Loop.OuterLoop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the supplied sample pretty much covers everything you need to know, the loop tracker isn't as mysterious as you might think.

All `Loop.OuterLoop` is doing is referencing the parent loop if you're in one and it's being tracked, for example:

```
@{
  int[] outerThings = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
  var innerThings = new[] {"a","b","c", "d"};

  foreach (int outerThing in outerThings.Track())
  {
    <li>@outerThing

    @foreach(var innerThing in innerThings.Track())
    {
      <li>---->@innerThing

      @if (Loop.OuterLoop.First)
      {
        <strong>Start of outer loop (index is: @Loop.OuterLoop.Index)</strong>  
      }

      @if (Loop.OuterLoop.Last)
      {
        <strong>end of outer loop (index is: @Loop.OuterLoop.Index)</strong>  
      }
      </li>
    }
    </li>
  }
}
```

Under the bonnet the helper is just wrapping access to your arrays, lists and collections and tracking forward movement through these items with an incrementing internal index value.

**Update:**

Here's an example using three nested loops with the very inner loop referencing the most outer loop (`outerThings`):

```
@{
  int[] outerThings = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
  var middleThings = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
  var innerThings = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

  foreach (int outerThing in outerThings.Track())
  {
    <li>@outerThing

    @foreach(var middleThing in middleThings.Track())
    {
      <li>---->@middleThing

      @foreach(var innerThing in innerThings.Track())
      {
        <li>-----+---->@innerThing

        @if (Loop.OuterLoop.OuterLoop.First)
        {
          <strong>
            Start of outerThing loop (index is: @Loop.OuterLoop.OuterLoop.Index)
          </strong>  
        }

        @if (Loop.OuterLoop.OuterLoop.Last)
        {
          <strong>
            End of outerThing loop (index is: @Loop.OuterLoop.OuterLoop.Index)
          </strong>  
        }
        </li>
      }
      </li>
    }
    </li>
  }
}
```

Comment: What would happen if there's a 3rd loop, it just blows up?

Comment: @chris - I added another example using three nested loops. You just reference the very outer loop from the very inner loop by adding an extra `OuterLoop` e.g. `Loop.OuterLoop.OuterLoop`

Comment: With that being said, I bet programming that property wasn't fun .

Answer (score 1):

Tracking the OuterLoop isn't entirely difficult. The helper stores its state in Context.Items which ensures request-level isolation. Each time a new loop is tracked, it checks to see if a value is already present in Context.Items and assigns it to the new loop as the OuterLoop property. When the enumerator is disposed, the value in Context.Items is set to OuterLoop effectively popping the current loop.

```
foo.Track()
   fooWrapper.OuterLoop = Content.Items["Loop"] // null at this point.
   Context.Items["Loop"] = fooWrapper

bar.Track()
   barWrapper.OuterLoop = Content.Items["Loop"] // fooWrapper
   Context.Items["Loop"] = barWrapper

bar.Dispose()
   Context.Items["Loop"] = barWrapper.OuterLoop // Current in fooWraper
```

This means you could have any depth of loops, including ones that span across pages and it would still work.

Note that the helper wouldn't work in a multi-threaded scenario and might work erratically if you fail to dispose the enumerator.

Comment: I'm perplexed by the statements you raised on disposing the enumerator, none of the code samples ever showed disposing the enumerator. Also where does `Wrap()` come from?

Comment: @Chris My bad, I meant to say Track but wrote Wrap instead. I've changed that in my response. Also, IEnumerator<T> implements IDisposable and if you use a regular foreach(), the compiler ensures that it is correctly Disposed. You would need to worry about calling Dispose if you choose to iterate over the Enumerator yourself. var enumerator = myEnumerable.GetEnumerator(); ...